# Precompiling assets failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I am pushing to an app I haven't updated in months and am running into this problem. I only changed a few variables in my code. No idea why its suddenly doing this to me.

```
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:myapp.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:myapp.git'


   rake aborted!
   could not connect to server: Connection refused
   Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
   TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
   /tmp/build_8c6e6263-c5c9-44ac-88ad-7eadb7c4c0e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1216:in `initialize'
   /tmp/build_8c6e6263-c5c9-44ac-88ad-7eadb7c4c0e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1216:in `new'
   /tmp/build_8c6e6263-c5c9-44ac-88ad-7eadb7c4c0e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1216:in `connect'
   /tmp/build_8c6e6263-c5c9-44ac-88ad-7eadb7c4c0e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:324:in `initialize'
   /tmp/build_8c6e6263-c5c9-44ac-88ad-7eadb7c4c0e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `new'
   /tmp/build_8c6e6263-c5c9-44ac-88ad-7eadb7c4c0e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `postgresql_connection'
   /tmp/build_8c6e6263-c5c9-44ac-88ad-7eadb7c4c0e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
   /tmp/build_8c6e6263-c5c9-44ac-88ad-7eadb7c4c0e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
   /tmp/build_8c6e6263-c5c9-44ac-88ad-7eadb7c4c0e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
   /tmp/build_8c6e6263-c5c9-44ac-88ad-7eadb7c4c0e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
   /tmp/build_8c6e6263-c5c9-44ac-88ad-7eadb7c4c0e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
   /tmp/build_8c6e6263-c5c9-44ac-88ad-7eadb7c4c0e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
   /tmp/build_8c6e6263-c5c9-44ac-88ad-7eadb7c4c0e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
   /tmp/build_8c6e6263-c5c9-44ac-88ad-7eadb7c4c0e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
   /tmp/build_8c6e6263-c5c9-44ac-88ad-7eadb7c4c0e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
   /tmp/build_8c6e6263-c5c9-44ac-88ad-7eadb7c4c0e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
   /tmp/build_8c6e6263-c5c9-44ac-88ad-7eadb7c4c0e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
   /tmp/build_8c6e6263-c5c9-44ac-88ad-7eadb7c4c0e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:308:in `clear_cache!'
   /tmp/build_8c6e6263-c5c9-44ac-88ad-7eadb7c4c0e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:104:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
```

Comment: There must be a stack trace to indicate what failed. Could you add the first few lines from there?

Comment: See my answer below. Let me know if it didn't resolve your issue.

Comment: Please accept an answer if it resolved your problem. Helps to clear the clutter from the question stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common reasons for asset recompilation issues can be found [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#assets-precompile-failures) on the heroku support page.

Based on the mention of Postgres in the error message, I would try changing the following line in your config/application.rb to **false** like so: `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false`.

Answer (score 1):

You should prevent initializing your application and connecting to the database by ensuring that the following line is in your config/application.rb:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```