# Random ActionView::Template::Error ( isn't precompiled):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

Randomly my app is giving the error: `ActionView::Template::Error ( isn't precompiled):` on one of my controller actions.

It was working fine earlier and then just stopped working. I haven't pushed to heroku or anything..

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Ive tried running `heroku run rake assets:precompile` with no luck.

I did however have [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20040342/precompiling-assets-failed) the other day, could it be related?

Full Error:

```
2013-11-19T04:44:35.306982+00:00 app[web.1]:     18: <tr>
2013-11-19T04:44:35.306982+00:00 app[web.1]:     19: <% @accounts.each do |a| %>
2013-11-19T04:44:35.306982+00:00 app[web.1]:     20:    <tr>
2013-11-19T04:44:35.306982+00:00 app[web.1]:     21:        <td style="text-align:left;" class="list"><%= image_tag a.image %> <%= a.name %> <% if a.verified == true %> <img src="/images/verified.png" title ="Verified account" alt="Verified account" style="height:18px;"><% end %>
2013-11-19T04:44:35.306982+00:00 app[web.1]:     22:            <br> <%= link_to "Purchase", "/#{a.permalink}" %> | <%= link_to "Visit twitter", a.url, :rel => 'nofollow', :target => "new" %></td> 
2013-11-19T04:44:35.306982+00:00 app[web.1]:     23:        <td class="list">$<%= number_with_delimiter(a.price, :delimiter => ',') %></td>
2013-11-19T04:44:35.306982+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-11-19T04:44:35.306982+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error ( isn't precompiled):
2013-11-19T04:44:35.306982+00:00 app[web.1]:     24:        <% if a.retweets %>
2013-11-19T04:44:35.307215+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/market/_list.html.erb:19:in `_app_views_market__list_html_erb___3570010844875364888_70106042012700'
2013-11-19T04:44:35.307215+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-11-19T04:44:35.307215+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/market/index.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_market_index_html_erb___4051548369069171146_70106041975580'
```

Comment: Can you post the whole error you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `a.image` is coming back `nil` or blank, so it is trying to find the asset "" and failing.

Comment: I just realized that as well. Someone must've deleted the image they had hosted elsewhere.